# What's the difference between uniformly equicontinuous and uniformly continuous?

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

I am very confused. Thanks in advance.
Our definition is that:

Uniformly Equicontinuous: $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0 \ such \ that \ |s-t|< \delta \ and \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ then \ |f_n(t)-f_n(s)|<\epsilon$

Uniformly continuous:  $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0 \ such \ that \ \forall s,t \in [a,b], \ |s-t|< \delta \ and \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ then \ |f_n(t)-f_n(s)|<\epsilon$

Comment: Uniform continuity is a property of a single function. Uniform equicontinuity is a property of a _family_ of functions. [Uniform equicontinuity implies that every member of the family is uniformly continuous, but it's more than just that.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $E,E'$ are metric spaces then a function $f:E\to E'$ is *uniformly continuous* if for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$\sup\{d'(f(x),f(y)) : d(x,y)<\delta\}<\varepsilon.$$
A family of functions $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$ from $E$ to $E'$ is *uniformly equicontinuous* if for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$\sup_{\alpha\in I}\sup\{d'(f_\alpha(x),f_\alpha(y)) : d(x,y)<\delta\}<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 32):

The family of function $(f_n)$ defined on $[a,b]$ is said :

**Uniformly equicontinuous :**
$\forall \epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall s,t \in [a,b], \ |s-t|< \delta \  \Rightarrow \ |f_n(t)-f_n(s)|<\epsilon$

**Uniformly continuous :**
$\forall \epsilon>0,\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\exists\delta>0, \forall s,t \in [a,b], \ |s-t|< \delta \  \Rightarrow \ |f_n(t)-f_n(s)|<\epsilon$

Look at the place of $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. In the first case, you have the same $\delta$ for the whole family of functions. While in the second case, the $\delta$ may depend on the function you are considering. One can remark that uniform equicontinuity implies uniform continuity. So uniform equicontinuity is a more strong condition.

Comment: Hi Nico, do you not think it would be a good idea to label $\delta$ as $\delta_n$ for the second case to avoid such a possible confusion/ambiguity?

Comment: Hi. In this answer or in general ? In this answer I think it is better to let it that way. Indeed, this emphasizes the fact that the place in which you put things does really matter. Making a difference would be nice if the confusion could occur in a proof for example. @jamesmartini